# Run puppeteer on GKE Autopilot without disabling sandbox

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to run Puppeteer on GKE Autopilot without disabling the sandbox.

My image works perfectly fine on Google Cloud Run, but doesn't on GKE Autopilot.

Running the image locally with Docker needs `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` but adding this capability on GKE Autopilot results on the following error:

```
linux capability 'SYS_ADMIN' on container 'xxxxx-1' not allowed; Autopilot only allows the capabilities: 'AUDIT_WRITE,CHOWN,DAC_OVERRIDE,FOWNER,FSETID,KILL,MKNOD,NET_BIND_SERVICE,NET_RAW,SETFCAP,SETGID,SETPCAP,SETUID,SYS_CHROOT,SYS_PTRACE'
```

I tried to set all the allowed capabilities returned in this error but it didn't work.

Do you know any trick to make this work? Is disabling the sandbox the only solution here?

Here is my Dockerfile for reference:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . .

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile \
    && yarn build \
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

CMD node dist/server.js
```

Comment: Autopilot has less flexibility than GKE standard. The error message you are getting basically says it all. You cannot have the capability SYS_ADMIN on a container running on GKE Autopilot. The only workaround i can think of is using GKE standard mode

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. I was hoping to find a workaround because Cloud RUN product allows to run puppeteer with a sandbox. I thought Autopilot had "at least" the same permissions than Cloud RUN, or maybe a different configuration that I'm missing.

Comment: Cloud Run and GKE Autopilot are different products ;)

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought, anyways, thank you for your time! Have a nice day!